# Unable to implement dropping pin animation on map markers in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-animation

I am trying to implement `dropping pin` effect on the map markers. I have implemented the code as below but I can't find the animation occurring on the marker. Can anyone guide me step by step how to do it.

```
    final LatLng latlang = new LatLng(15.4989, 73.8278);
    final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlang).title("Hello Maps ");
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlang, 17));
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = mGoogleMap.getProjection();

    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / 1000);
            double lng = t * latlang.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * latlang.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
            Log.i("marker thread","elapsed"+elapsed+",t"+t+"lng,"+lng+",lat"+lat);
            marker.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));



        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in your code,

firstly, your handler never reply itself, it is just waiting for one second. To fix it, you have to call your handler within your handler like `handler.postDelayed(this, 16);` until your `t >= 1` (One second)

secondly, you should have wait 0.016 seconds, rather than 1 whole seconds for your outer handler call.

lastly, your "marker", is actually the markerOption, so your code should looked like this instead:

```
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latlang).title("Hello Maps ");
    final Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

and do rather than using `marker.position`, you do `marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));`